# Disable spellcheck in h:inputtextarea using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

What I'm trying is in the title.

So I have in my jsf page :

```
    <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" />
    <h:outputScript name="jquery.js" /> 
    <h:outputScript target="head">
        $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(function() {});
        $("#question").attr("spellcheck",false);
        $('textarea').attr("spellcheck",false);
    </h:outputScript>
```

and below

```
    <h:inputTextarea id="question" cols="90" rows="20" value="#{myBean.question}" />
```

But it's not working.

I also tried

```
$("#question").val("hello world");
```

It's also not working.

And last try to be sure the code is executed

```
        alert('Hello World');
```

The popup appears but nothing else.

What's the problem ?

Comment: does this work ? `$(document).ready(function() { $('textarea').attr("spellcheck",false);});`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding quotation marks to false like below:

```
$("#question").attr("spellcheck","false");
$('textarea').attr("spellcheck","false");
```